# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on function controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I know there are others questions with same title, but I can't find the error.

My view looks like here:

```
<table class="table">
                <thead style="color:white">
                  <tr>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>ID<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>SLUG<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>ORDER<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>PUBLIC<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr id="{{$project->id}}">
                      <td>{{$project->id}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
</table>
```

**Ajax code**

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});

$("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            type:'POST',
            data: newOrder
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
            // render table with new order?
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

**Url on web.php:**

```
Route::post('projects/updateOrder', ['uses' => 'AdminController@updateOrder', 'as' => 'admin.projects.updateOrder']);
```

**Controller error with the error**

```
public function updateOrder(Request $request){
        $ids = $request->ids;
        $caseQuery = 'CASE id ';
        foreach ( $ids as $order => $id) {
            $caseQuery .= "WHEN $id THEN $order";
        }
        $caseQuery .= 'END CASE';

        DB::table('projects')->whereIn('id',$ids)
                             ->update(['order' => '$caseQuery']);
    }
```

If I put a return of `$ids` don't get anything.
If I check the data passed pass all the Id's.

What i'm trying? Get the new values of ids when I make a drag 'n' drop and order it with ajax.

If have any question feel free to ask it.

How to fix the error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `var_dump($ids);` - that will show you what it actually contains.

Comment: `/home/vagrant/Code/web/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php:120:null`

Comment: Value of $ids is null, but if I check navigator with web developer tool data is passed

Comment: Please include what that looks like.

Comment: The var_dump show this: `/home/vagrant/Code/web/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.‌​php:120:null` . The web developer show this: `25,19,27,26,23,18,28,14,24,20,12,13,17,29,15,21,16,22,4,3,1,6,9,8,5,2,10,11,7:` these are the id's.

Comment: You are passing id as string ,
please echo and see that string an explode it to convert as array.. and in you ajax post  data : {ids: newOrder }

Comment: I just edit the code en put the `{ids: newOrder}` on data, get the same error but pass all the array. Can check the var_dump info on the answer of @Scosu

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything named `ids` in your view or ajax code. I think the problem is related to this. 
As far as I know, jQuery UI sortable `toArray` method return only an array of IDs. So you should name the array yourself in Ajax code like this:

```
$("tbody").sortable({
items: "> tr",
appendTo: "parent",
helper: "clone",
update: function( event, ui ) {
    let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
        type:'POST',
        data: { ids: newOrder }
    })
   .done(function( msg ) {
        // render table with new order?
   });
}
}).disableSelection();
```

Notice the "`{ids: newOrder }`" part.

I didn't have enough time to test it but you can try and give me a feedback. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for your fast answer. I just checked too i don't have anything called ids on ajax function, I try your code but get same error. If I do a var_dump of $ids get this `/home/vagrant/Code/web/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php:120:string '2,4,5,6,1,3,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29' (length=77)
`

Comment: explode the string $ids = explode(',' , $request->ids);

Comment: Hi @Shibon Thanks, well step by step. Now I get this: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$caseQuery' for column 'order' at row 1 (SQL: update `projects` set `order` = $caseQuery where `id` in (2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29))

Comment: You can do like this
foreach ( $ids as $order => $id) {
DB::table('projects')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['order' => $order]);
}

Comment: @Shibon if you can, put an answer and we make the feedback in your answer. I will try your code now.

Comment: We are near to make it:) Now don't get any error. But when I make a drag 'n' drop make a new order of ALL projects.

Comment: I'm testing it. If I drag and drop they go to the inverse way. I'm not sure if I explain it good, F.e: If I drag and drop from 28 to 29 (makes from 2 to 1) and the value is 1.

Comment: Can you explain it some more.. @Lluis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153020/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-shibon).

Comment: @Shibon go chat please, maybe I think where's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also first try to print complete post data with below

```
 public function updateOrder(Request $request){
    print_r($request->all());
     ...........
 }
```

And get all id's in variable accordingly then use explode to convert it to array before passing it to whereIn clause.

Use this

```
$ids = explode(',' , $request->ids);
```

As [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) clause takes second parameter as array not string.

Comment: Hi @Naincy thanks for your fast answer, I pass the ids now in the data, and if I do print_r I get this: `Array ( [ids] => 2,4,6,1,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 )
` but anyway get the same error. `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
` Know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Naincy, if I explode the array I get this: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$caseQuery' for column 'order' at row 1 (SQL: update `projects` set `order` = $caseQuery where `id` in (2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29))`

Comment: See what's you getting in $caseQuery variable. and whats datatyoe of order column in DB

Comment: I do not see any code where you setting value to projects variable.

Comment: In caseQuery I get 'case id ', that's something I don't understand. And order field have integer values.

Comment: Well, i understand why I get 'case id' from caseQuery, but I don't understand why have this. I just get this from other question and can't understand it.

Comment: If you look the view code, you can see on `<tr>` I pass the ID of each project. But foreach, well, all the function of controller is weird..

Comment: Hey man, that <tr> I can see but where you setting its value in controller before sending to view that's my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153016/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-naincy).